# Outlook email mysteriously prefixed with "i>>?" when sending an HTML file

Tags: html, css, email, outlook, html-email

I have an `HTML` file that I'm going to use as a Microsoft Outlook email. The structure is simply

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>my title </title>
</head>
<body>
  ... 
</body>
</html>
```

although I've experimented with adding/subtracting `DOCTYPE` declarations, `charset` declarations, etc. The problem is that the email is getting prefixed with "***i>>?***" except with a raquo and upside-down question mark. You can see a screenshot here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vamnG.png Everything about the `HTML` file looks fine in Internet Explorer and the strange characters only show up when I go to "File->Send" and preview my email or when I actually send the email and receive it.

Any idea why this is or what I can experiment with to try and fix it?

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a UTF-8 BOM prefix. HTML files should not have prologs like that.

Comment: So what can I do about this?

Comment: Make sure when you create the file there us no such prefix?

Comment: Try opening in Word (I know, I hate myself too for saying it) - Outlook uses the MSWord HTML rendering engine anyway, so if opened and edited there it should correctly format it for sending out from Outlook and remove your issue.